# Historical aggregate Twitter data

Tags: api, twitter

I want to graph the number of tweets and the number of followers over the last three months, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that either through the API or any ready-made tool.

I tried TwitterCounter, but the data they provided was basically the result of some sort of interpolation function, not based on actual historical data.

Is there a way to get historical aggregate data from Twitter (not the actual tweets, but the sums, averages, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such numbers. Or not that I am aware of them. Before they updated their tweet id algorithm it was possible to estimate the numbers of tweets per day via a simple difference, but now - since they use a different algorithm to create the ids - it is not possible anylonger.

You could try if google's twitter search could give you some stats.

What do you mean with the 'number of followers'? Whose followers?

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling this was the case. By number of followers I meant the number of followers one particular user has over time. I'll have a look at Google Twitter search.

Comment: "the number of followers one particular user has over time" this is relative cheap to reach. getting the number of followers costs only 1 API point => ~350 users / h => ~200 k users each month are possible